# create drop down tab with CSS pseudo class :hover

Tags: css, sass

I have a page with a topbar which contains a list which conatins the tab I'm trying to drop when the 'about' link is hovered over by the user.

```
  <!-- page top bar -->
    <div id="topBar">
        <ul class="dropper">
            <li>

                <a id="about" >
                    About
                </a>

                <ul>
                    <span class="dropTab">
                    <img class="thumb" src="assets/images/StephenBW.jpg"/>
                    <p>
                        This blog is written by ...
                    </p>
                    </span>
                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>    
    </div>
```

here's the (s)css

```
 #topBar{
@include goldTopper;
top:0px;
display:block;
@include bar;
margin: auto;
@include containerShadow;
border-bottom:1px solid gold; border-top-color:#FF9;
ul, ul li {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    position:relative;
}

#about {
    padding-left:8px; 
    color:#836B15;
    font-weight:850;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute; top:15px;

}

p{
    color:#836B15;
    font-weight:850;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear:left;
}

li ul {
    span{}
}
}

#about:hover {
.dropTab{
    display:block;
}

}

.dropTab {
display:none;
top:47px;left:8px;position:absolute;
width:285px; height:625px; @include whiteGradient; padding:6px;
border-bottom:solid 1.5px; border-left:solid 1.5px; border-right:solid 1.5px;
p{
    font-size:10pt;
}
}

.thumb {
height:131px; display:inline;
float:left; padding:10px;
}
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why. The question as clearly as I can put it is, How do I make the drop tab drop when the about link is hovered over using only css?

Comment: Your second UL should contain an LI as it's not valid right now. A good place to start with drop downs is http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: First time I am seeing this style of writing. An element style inside style of another element!

Comment: Wrap your nested `ul` inside of the About anchor (`a`)

Answer (score 0):

A small change in css does the trick.

```
#about:hover {
.dropTab{
    display:block;
}

}

.dropTab {
display:none;
top:47px;left:8px;position:absolute;
width:285px; height:625px; @include whiteGradient; padding:6px;
border-bottom:solid 1.5px; border-left:solid 1.5px; border-right:solid 1.5px;
p{
    font-size:10pt;
}
}
```

TO

```
#about ul{
 display:none;   
}
#about:hover ul{
    display:block;

}

.dropTab {
top:47px;left:8px;position:absolute;
width:285px; height:625px; @include whiteGradient; padding:6px;
border-bottom:solid 1.5px; border-left:solid 1.5px; border-right:solid 1.5px;
p{
    font-size:10pt;
}
}
```

And also added the missing li

May not be perfect (removed positioning styles of the span & missing imports), but hover is now working: http://jsfiddle.net/pPkLQ/